# Create Free Shipping Coupon

Tags: shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, ce-1.7.0.2, coupon, free-shipping

I have trouble to setup a free shipping coupon in Magento 1.7.0.2. The coupon itself will be applied successfully but the Free Shipping Method doesn't appear.

Actually I want to setup a coupon which enables (UPS) free shipping for all items.

I was wondering if I have to enable (any) Free Shipping Method first? But then Free Shipping will also show up if no Coupon got applied.

Do I miss something? Here are my configuration settings:

**Shopping Cart Price Rules**

```
Status: Active
Website: Main Website
Customer Groups: ALL
Coupon: Specific Coupon
Coupon Code: FREE1
Uses per Coupon:
Uses per Customer: 0
From Date:
To Date:
Priority:

Condition: If ALL of these conditions are TRUE: Shipping Country is United States
Apply: Percent of product price discount
Discount Amount: 0
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 0
Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0
Apply to Shipping Amount: Yes
Free Shipping: For shipment with matching items
Stop Further Rules Processing: No
```

**Shipping Methods:**

```
Free Shipping 
Enabled: No

UPS
Enabled for Checkout: Yes
Free Method: UPS Ground
Free Shipping with Minimum Order Amount: Enable
Minimum Order Amount for Free Shipping: 100000000
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

please check bellow links:

http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-create-coupon-codes-in-magento-beginners-tutorial-1/

http://creatingawebstore.com/how-to-create-a-free-shipping-coupon-or-promotion-in-magento.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680951/magento-free-shipping-and-coupon-discount

https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/free-shipping-with-coupon-code-in-mag/

http://www.ifuelinteractive.com/how-to-create-a-free-shipping-coupon/

**I hope this will help you.**